# Multiplattform password safe

Tags: password-management

I'm looking for a password safe/manager software which runs on Windows, OS X and iOS. Since we are several people using the same database/file, it's very important for us, that it can synchronize changes automatically.

Currently we are using keepass 2.x . Unfortunately using it with mono on OS X is such a pain, that we need something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I installed Parallels Desktop and the Windows Version 2.18 on the Mac. The Windows and iPhone Versions are fine.

Answer (score 2):

[LastPass](http://www.lastpass.com) will do the trick. It supports Windows, Linux, Mac, and mobile platforms. However, mobile is available only with the $1/mo. subscription.

The system is cloud-based so it syncs automatically. In case you need offline access to your passwords, they have [LastPass Pocket](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=2406&questiondefault=offline) app.

Comment: Do I get this right, that all our PWs are stored in the cloud and readable by LastPass?

Comment: @BetaRide: Yes, they are stored in the "cloud" and no, they are encrypted on the local system.

Comment: If you're worried about unauthorized access to your passwords, LastPass supports [many multi-factor authentication methods](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=1696&questiondefault=grid).

Comment: That sounds good. I'll give it a try.

Comment: +1: Lastpass is the way to go. Plus these folks have previously shown that they are paranoid enough to put security over PR.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as BetaRide.. I have my KeePass database file in a dropbox folder that's accessible to me on all the machines I need it on.. to me it seems the advantage of that over LastPass is that even a compromise of dropbox doesn't expose my encrypted KeePass database file. Of course I still have the OSX compatibility issue. I hope there is a solution that addresses both issues.

Answer (score 1):

Keepass 1.x is available in a version that runs on OS-X with x11. [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/)  unfortunately, this forces you to use 1.x on your Windows/Linux clients too.

Comment: KeePass 1.x cannot synchronize automatically. So this not an option for us.

Comment: True.  However, you can store the .kdb file in a shared location and it will manage locking the the file when accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

[1password](https://agilebits.com/products/1password) works on the platforms you need and has Dropbox sync support. It's not cheap though.